# Finnair get price separation on return ticket

Tags: air-travel, finnair, return-tickets

I have booked return tickets from Finnair, London to Helsinki. Is there anyway to split the ticket price for each way? I called to Finnair costumer service, but they were not so helpful. Any help?

Comment: You’ve already booked? And why do you want to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "split the ticket price"?

Comment: Are you trying to split the ticket into two one-way tickets? And possibly not use the first leg, London to Helsinki?

Comment: I have booked the return ticket Hel-Lon on the wrong date, so I had to buy a new return ticket from a different airline , because my return ticket was not exchangeable. Now I need to claim for the reimbursement from my work place. But I can not because I need to know the price of one way ticket plus my return ticket. I need to know what was the price of outbound and return flights separately.

Comment: @EcatrinaSmith is this something you have discussed with your workplace, as in how they want to break the costs down?  By booking a return (at cost X) and then a single (at cost Y), and claiming for one segment of the return (at cost Z) and the single, you are potentially claiming for more money than just the return due to the high price of single tickets.  So make sure your work place is on board with however you break the expenses down.

Answer (score 2):

Check the confirmation email with the ticket details; often, it contains a cryptic-looking line with those details. Here is an example for a random pick JFK to FRA:

`NYC DL FRA Q75.00 652.50QKVJ00B2 DL X/AMS Q7.45 DL NYC 210.50UKVY00B2 NUC 945.45 END ROE 1.00 XT 5.89YC 7.00XY 3.96XA 37.20US 5.60AY 10.50DE 46.00OY 29.50RA 7.20CJ 7.10RN 350.00YR 4.50XF JFK4.50`

If you spent a bit of thought over the abbreviations (and some google time), you can identify each leg and each tax and fee, and through that calculate the piece you care about.

Here is the respective string for a Finnair LHR-HEL (London Heathrow to Helsinki), in January 2020:
`LON AY HEL 22.55ZLI2GB AY LON 22.55ZLI2GB NUC 45.10 END ROE 0.775934 XT 15.45GB 20.69UB 4.88DQ 8.88FI 1.00XU 35.66YR`

Google's itasoftware explains it as:

[image]

So the first two numbers (22.55) are 20.79 Euro (in USD - I accidentially called it up in USD); 45.10 is the sum of the two; and the rest matches 1:1 - 15.45GB is "United Kingdom Air Passenger Duty APD, etc.

If you don't have that string, this obviously won't work. You could try to find a future flight with the same price you paid, and analyze that one accordingly, if they accept that - or simply divide the total by 2.

Comment: Would you mind explaining some of that cryptic text and what to Google?

Comment: Just checked, none of my tickets purchased in the last 10 years have this information on it - looks like its highly airline specific.